# Slick slider doesn't slide as expected with variable width

Tags: slider, slick.js

I have a slider made with slick slider, i want to have the slick current a different width and add a transition when moving from the width of slick-slide to the slick current one.
https://codepen.io/maipo89/pen/qBgMoEa
I want the current slide to stay fixed on the left, i tried to replicate the error on this codepen but it doesn't add the slick current class on page load. when i click next arrow the transition doesn't move smootly.
thank you for the help

$('.colums__swiper').slick({
dots: false,
slidesToShow: 5,
slidesToScroll: 1,
arrows: true,
variableWidth: true,
infinite: true,
speed: 700,
waitForAnimate: true,
nextArrow: '',
});

```
$('.colums__swiper__slide').on('mouseenter', function() {
    // On hover, remove slick-current class from all slides
    $('.colums__swiper__slide').removeClass('slick-current');
    // Add slick-current class to the hovered slide
    $(this).addClass('slick-current');
});

$('.colums__swiper .next-arrow').on('click', function() {
    // Add a class to hide the slider with a transition
    $('.colums__swiper').addClass('hide-slider');

    // Wait for a few seconds and then remove the class to make the slider reappear
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.colums__swiper').removeClass('hide-slider');
    }, 500); // Adjust the time (in milliseconds) as needed
});


$('.colums__swiper .slick-prev').on('click', function() {
    // Add a class to hide the slider with a transition
    $('.colums__swiper').addClass('hide-slider');

    // Wait for a few seconds and then remove the class to make the slider reappear
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.colums__swiper').removeClass('hide-slider');
    }, 500); // Adjust the time (in milliseconds) as needed
});
```

});